# custom API path URL using Vue/heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, vue.js, heroku

I've just finished building a full-stack project with Vue, Node, Express, Mongoose, and MongoDB. I need help figuring out what to do in Vue in all the places that the API is called the path is, `http://localhost:PORT/api/v1/` but I know this won't work for deployment. What could I do about this? Also, I want others to use this app and API so are there any things to consider over things such as CORS, allowing access to different URL paths, etc? I'm wondering how this could be done in order to deploy on Heroku.

This project is a test project for a company I'm interviewing for so I really need this to be working by the time they get the project and try to use it for themselves.

```
fetchData(){
                if (sessionStorage.homeVideos) {
                    // console.log('Getting from session storage...');
                    this.videos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.homeVideos);
                } else {
                    // console.log('Getting from API and setting res to session storage...');
                    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/videos')
                    .then(res => {
                        sessionStorage.setItem('homeVideos', JSON.stringify(res.data.data.videos));
                        this.videos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.homeVideos);
                    })
                    .catch(err => alert("ERROR: " + err.response.data.message));
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can remove protocol and host part of the url and everything will be fine. Your front-end will send ajax request to your host anyway

Comment: What about when it's hosted on heroku?

Comment: It will work anyway. There is no difference where it will be hosted

Comment: I've just taken the protocol and localhost part out and tried running the app but it hit an error and failed

Comment: Show me the code which fired an error. Was it an ajax request or something else?

Comment: I've just added it. Btw, backend server runs on port 8000 while vue server gives me 8082. Sometimes the vue port changes on its own and I'm not sure why, when that happens, I have to allow access to the new port in the backend code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214531/discussion-between-andreycrane-and-albert-anthony6).